# google sheets : send several sheets in pdf with several email-adress

Tags: email, pdf, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I try use google script for google sheets. 
I found two scripts that I would like merge :

- the first allows to send a sheet like pdf by mail : I found it in stackoverflow.
  The email-adress is in the particular cell in every sheets.
- The second send several sheets of spreadsheet in a zip by email :
  The part of script which interest me is

```
     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 

  var sheets = ss.getSheets(); 

   for (var i=0; i<sheets.length; i++) {

}
```

My aim is to send one mail with one pdf at one student. I have as many sheets as students.

I am not be able to do this.

Could you help me ? thank you

Comment: Welcome. The question needs more focus. Please edit the question to include an specific programming question as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: There are lots of emails on SO.  With a little diligence you should be able to find something to help you achieve your goals. Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and [mcve]. [Google Apps Script Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script).